# How to create a handleChange function for dynamic input object of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, object

I am creating an invoice generator for my personal project so I can learn and understand the MERN stack better. I currently have this as part of my state. I currently have my className linked to my CSS, as I learned that could be manipulated to use create the handleChange function, so I wasn't sure if I needed to completely change that. I have tried working with index, by mapping each object to it's index, but it's just been confusing.

```
state = {
...
 itemValues: [{ 
                description:  "",
                rate: "",
                quantity: "",
                amount: "",
                tax: ""
            }],
...
}
```

and this as my mapped value

```
 itemValues.map((item, i) => {
                                let descId = `description-${i}`;
                                let rateId = `rate-${i}`;
                                let quanId = `quantity-${i}`;
                                let amonId = `amount-${i}`;
                                let taxId = `tax-${i}`;
                                return(
                                    <div key={i} className="item-row">
                                        <input 
                                        className="item item-description"
                                            type="text"
                                            id={descId}
                                            name={descId}
                                            placeholder="Item description"
                                            data-id={descId}
                                            onChange={this.handleChange('desc')}
                                            
                                             />
                                            {/* */}

                                            <input className="item item-rate"
                                            type="text"
                                            id={rateId}
                                            name={rateId}
                                            placeholder="Item rate"
                                            data-id={rateId}
                                            
                                             />
                                            {/* */}
                                            <input className="item item-quantity"
                                            id="item-quantity"
                                            type="text"
                                            placeholder="item quantity"
                                            data-id={quanId}
                                            
                                             />
                                            {/* */}
                                            <input className="item item-amount"
                                            id="item-amount"
                                            type="text"
                                            placeholder="item amount"
                                            data-id={amonId}
                                            
                                             />
                                            {/* */}
                                            
                                            {this.state.taxation === "None" ? "" : <input class="item item-tax"
                                            id="item-tax"
                                            type="text"
                                            placeholder="tax(%)"
                                            data-id={taxId}
                                            
                                            
                                             />}

                                        <input type='button' value='remove' onClick={this.removeClick}
                                    />
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
```

I'm not sure how to set my handleChange function, to allow dynamic inputs to be saved.

Comment: You can start with providing how you component is setup. Are we talking about functional or class components?

Comment: @Delice Apologies for not including it, but it's a class component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since is a mapping into a global component like `itemValuesComponent` for example, you need more than one function or an index as well to set items values into the state.

You can try the follow:

```
const handleChange = (location, property) => (e) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    itemValues: [...prevState.itemValues.slice(0, location),
      {
        ...prevState.itemValues[location],
        [property]: e.target.value,
      }
    , ...prevState.itemValues.slice(location)]
  }))
}
```

and when you need it:

```
<input
  ...
  onChange={this.handleChange(i,'description')}
/>
```

Please, let me know if this work.

Try to use React Hooks, I'm pretty sure that it will simplify your code.

Comment: It says TypeError: prevState.slice is not a function or its return value is not iterable. I have tried react hooks, but it's not allowing me to use hooks with a class component

Comment: Howdy @MichaelKwanzaa, I made an update. `...prevState.itemValues.slice(location)]`. Try again, and let me know.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!. It just keeps increasing the array and adding new arrays per type, but that might be something with my code.